# Get value of td with php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 file action.php and main.php:

Currently I want to check my td value after clicking the button 'Confirm' and if value of td from main.php (name="dist_'.$iid.'" id="dist_'.$i.'") is not "-" then I want to send it to database.
That td can be changed after clicking the button "Add value"

In action.php

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="add" onclick="multiply()">Add value</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="confirm_btn">Confirm</button>
</div>
```

In main.php(is included in action.php) I have this type of code

```
        $i=0;
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $iid = $row["iid"];
                echo '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="checked_'.$i
                .'" > &nbsp; </td>
                      <th scope="row">'.($i+1).'</th>
                      <td>'.$row["code"].'</td>
                      <td>'.$price.'</td>
                       <td name="dist_'.$iid.'" id="dist_'.$i.'" >-</td>
                    </tr>';
                    $i++;
                    
            }
         $result->free();
        }
        $mysqli->close();
```

Script part of main.php

```
 <script>
        let i = document.querySelectorAll('[name^=check]').length;
        function multiply(){
        for (let k = 0; k<i; k++) { 
            let checkBox = document.getElementById("checked_"+k);
            if (checkBox.checked === true) {
                document.getElementById("dist_"+k).innerHTML = 100+k;          
                                            }
                                   }}
    </script>
```

So how can I get value of td with php?

Comment: PHP can parse HTML, but I suspect, that is not, what you really need. There is an option to add a front-end verification, but.. on which stage do you expect the "-" to be changed to something else, an "input box", for example?

Comment: After clicking the button "Add value" "-" wil be changed. And if I want to confirm it with the button "Confirm", I want to send changes to Database. I don't know how can I check the value td(dist_) after clicking 2 buttons

Comment: Ok, I think, I get your idea, but don't think it is thought through well enough. Start from changing `<td name="dist_'.$iid.'" id="dist_'.$i.'" >-</td>` to `<td><input type="text" name="dist_'.$iid.'" id="dist_'.$i.'" value="-"></td>`, imo

Comment: in the beginning it was like that, but I didn't want it to have table cell in design

Comment: Just style the input box with no border and everything, telling, that it is the input box :) Or you can use `<input type="hidden"`, and the copy of the value, printed in `<td>`, and manipulate them with JS..

Comment: Ok. Thank u very much.
Спасибо огромное

Comment: XD не за что! Have fun, learning all those ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
<td id="dist_td'.$i.'"><input type="hidden" name="dist_'.$iid.'" id="distbashx_'.$i.'" value="-" ></td>
```

in script

```
document.getElementById("dist_"+i).value = value; 
document.getElementById("dist_td" + i).innerHTML = value;
```